# ¿ Como actualizar los datos (props) de un componente hijo enviados desde un componente padre en vue js con vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Estoy recibiendo el evento de un socket que me trae los datos de un vehículo, necesito enviar estos datos a un componente donde me muestra los datos del mismo. Para esto realizo lo siguiente:

```
this.$router.push({name: 'vehiculo', params:{vehiculo}}).catch(error => {
     if (error.name != "NavigationDuplicated") throw error; 
});
```

donde `name: 'vehiculo'` es la ruta del componente hijo, y `params: { vehiculo }` es el objeto con los datos del vehículo, hasta ahí todo bien.
Lo que ocurre es que necesito actualizar los datos que recibo desde el socket cada ves que este reaccione y enviarlo al componente hijo y actualizar los datos cargados.

De la manera que lo estoy haciendo no me actualiza los datos, me imagino que tendría que volver a renderizar la vista pero no se me ocurre una manera para hacerlo. ¿ alguna idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías añadir un watch en el componente padre mirando cambios en el `route`.

```
export default {
    watch: {
        '$route': {
            handler() {
                // Actualizar datos
            },
            immediate: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Daniel Rodríguez Meza , muchas gracias por la respuesta, soy nuevo con vue js, como podría llamar el watch, lo necesito es en el componente hijo, entonces tendría que utilizarlo allí y llamarlo desde el padre, correcto?

Comment: Tienes que llamarlo en el componente en donde estes actualizando los datos